# PHP session and Ajax

Tags: ajax, php

I've created a session variable and stored a value "123456" in it.
I need that value on another page that is called using ajax. I cannot access the session variable when making the ajax call. session_start() is in top of both pages. I even tried to write the actual session value to a txt file from the page that the ajax function calls, but the file turned out blank.

What to do?

Comment: You are probably doing something wrong, an ajax call is not much different then any other http request. Sharing the code might help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot access PHP session info from Javascript (I'm assuming that this is what you're trying to do).  You can pass it in as a hidden field or in the JS (dynamically added with PHP) to the second page, add it to a regular cookie, or provide it from PHP as a response to an AJAX request, but I think those are your only options.

Comment: Ok thanks... strange, everything else on the PHP page works as normal, one would think the session variable would work as well. Ok i think the best thing to do then is to pass it with the GET method.

Comment: @user1121487 is it on the same domain as the first page?